# android tests fail in jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I've setup a CI-server on Jenkins that will automize the build of an Android-app. When I skip the tests everything works fine.

```
clean build -x test
```

and I will receive apk's and a build which is finished with succes.
But when I'm not skipping the tests I get an error. My command is:

```
clean build
```

And I will get the following error:

```
    :app:testDebug

    Test > testnamse FAILED
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

   Test > testname FAILED
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

    Test > testname FAILED
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

    ...

    8 tests completed, 8 failed
    :app:testDebug FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
    > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:index.html
```

This .html shows the failed tests and the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. But the tests succeeded when the developer executed them with gradle on his local machien. They use gradle 2.2.1 while I'm using gradle 2.3 on the server. I don't know if that's an issue.

Comment: First find out if on the local machine all still works when you do a complete clean + rebuild. Sounds like local has kept some files from a previous build that make the tests execute correctly, while these files are not there on your jenkins machine

Comment: Thanks, good comment, I will tell it to the developers.

Comment: They've cleaned it and their build worked perfectly

Comment: Ok, also checked that all files (also test files) are commited to git I assume. Then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution: 
Add `testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'` in your app/build.gradle between the dependencies - tags.

Comment: You should be able to mark your own answer as correct, if so please do this so others know what was the correct answer easily when reading this page. Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Thanks, I will do it tommorow, not yet possible to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what your saying, I will assume that you are using some form of Source Control similar to GitHub. It is worth checking your repository and your ".ignore" file (if you are using GitHub).

An example of a good .ignore file would be something like this:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
/*/build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log
```

I have a feeling like your .jar files are not included in a check in, thus when Jenkins tried to build your .apk it cannot find the .jar files required and then fails. Your developers have the .jar files which is why they can compile the program. You should ask your developers to check the git.ignore (or similar) and fix it so that it looks like mine above. Check everything in, then try to build once more.

Comment: It looks the same except they have this in the beginning:

   `.gradle
   /local.properties
   /.idea/workspace.xml
   /.idea/libraries
   .DS_Store
   /build


#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_`

Might that be an issue?